# Difference between the consecutive terms of an increasing sequence consisting of positive integers composed of finitely many primes

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Suppose that $\{x_n\}$ is an increasing sequence whose elements are positive integers composed of finitely many primes $p_1, \dots, p_s$. I want to verify the following limit
$$ 
\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}-x_{n}=\infty.
$$
I have read a result that gives a lower bound for the difference between the consecutive terms of $\{x_n\}$ in the literature. This result implies that the difference between the consecutive terms diverges. However, can I elementarily show that the limit above is infinite?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3776547/prime-divisors-of-two-large-integers-which-are-close). I'm not sure how elementary Thue's result is.

Comment: @DanielFischer, can you see my proof once if it's correct or not?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer from Felipe Voloch](https://mathoverflow.net/a/18819/767) on mathoverflow.net is relevant:

> Yes, it is true that this kind of equation ax+by=c, where a,b,c are non-zero and fixed and x,y are allowed to only have prime factors in a finite set, has only finitely many solutions. This is a special case of Siegel's theorem on integral points on curves.

Choose $a=1$ and $b=-1$, so that $x-y=c$ has only finitely many solutions for any given $c$. Therefore there are only finitely many pairs $x,y$ with $|x-y|<M$ for any given $M$.

Unfortunately Siegel's theorem is by no means elementary. I suspect that there is no elementary proof.

Comment: can you see my proof once if it's correct or not?